# Nodejs +Mongodb can't configure async await

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Hi everyone I got just simple issue can't figured out. I'm getting array of texts and trying to translate it with `translatte api(Nodejs-npm)` then save it to mongoatlas. Here's my code

The problem is code the below works first so I can't get the filled array at time

```js
var texts = ["Certain", "Deduce", "Marauders"];
var data = [];

for (const element of texts) {
  const res = translatte(element, { to: "fr" })
    .then((trns) => {
      data({ text: element, translated_text: trns.text });
      //when I console.log(data) I can get values
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("err transalte");
    });
}

//In the below of the for loop works first so it return []
console.log("updated", data);
```

Then I gotta save it like

```js
const tData = new Table({
  data: data,
  name: "Data1"
});

const promise = tData.save();

promise.then((saved) => {
  return res.json(saved);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap this code into an `async` function so that you can `await` results for each `translatte` call and save it at the end.

I am assuming you're using `express` based on the `res.json(saved)` statement at the end, so you could do something like the following:

```js
app.post("/my-route", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    var texts = ["Certain", "Deduce", "Marauders"];
    var data = [];

    for (const element of texts) {
      const res = await translatte(element, { to: "fr" })
        .then((trns) => {
          data.push({text: element, translated_text: trns.text});
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("err transalte");
        });
    }
    console.log("updated", data);

    const tData = new Table({data: data, name: "Data1"});

    tData
      .save()
      .then((saved) => {
        res.status(200).json(saved);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(400).json({status: 400, message: error.message});
      });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({status: 400, message: error.message});
  }
});
```

Comment: Well Yes I works thank you much. I tryed all the for loop wrap in external asycn function but it workdes as old version. The issue is waiting for translate and then it solves.